# Why is bounce rate > 0% on visits with a site search?

Tags: google-analytics

As you know, a bounce occurs when only one page is viewed in a session.

When using the Site Search Usage reports (Behaviour > Site Search > Usage) and looking at visits WITH a site search, I'm seeing the bounce rate at 7%. How can this be true? When someone performs a search they would see at least two pages. Shouldn't visits with a site search show a bounce rate of 0%?

Has anyone come across this before? Do you know why this occurs? Any advise is very much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Maybe users have bookmarkes a search or you forgot to de-index your search page for Google SERPs. Check if there are entrances for your search page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when you've set up site search settings in GA you were asked to state a query parameter, which will be further used to determine if site search had place. What GA does is just check if this param exists in an url. If yes, site search was performed. It does not check history, referrer nor user actions on the website. What counts is this query param only.

>0% Bounce Rate on Site Search Visits may have place in such a situation:

1. Some is visiting your website and is performing site search
2. On the site with search results he does not continue his visit (ex. he closes mobile browser)
3. After some time (> 30 minutes) he reopens his mobile web browser
4. Usually web site is refreshed (if connection is available), which leads to another call of GA tracking script
5. User is exiting the web site without any further action

In such a scenario on point 3. user has performed another visit, but as he is not taking any extra actions (5.) it is counted as a Bounce. Web browser has remembered the site url, including site search query param, so it was send along with a tracking code and recognized by GA as a internal search.

It is a rather a common problem and it is rather hard to defend from it, as it is rather issue with web browsers, caching and remembering user's last step in the session rather then with your web site or GA settings.